How to refer to sub field in mongodb pipeline when the filed name includes "."
I defined following pipeline in Python. I hit an issue when a label includes . like "1.2.3".
labels.{label} becomes labels.1.2.3
$labels.{k} becomes $labels.1.2.3
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {"deleted": {"$ne": True}},  
                {
                    "$or": [
                        {f"labels.{label}": {"$exists": True}} for label in label_list
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "command": 1,
            "matching_labels": {
                k: f"$labels.{k}" for k in label_list
            }
        }
    }
]

I asked chatgpt but it failed to help with a solution. Could you help me out?
I tried using \. to escape the . and also [] instead of . but neither worked.
Example of documents:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "670cd0bae77a7a8a17abfb71"
  },
  "command": "show alarms ",
  "original": "show alarms",
  "labels": {
    "critical": 2,
    "rx": 1,
    "failure": 1,
    "6.5.3": 1,
    "isis": 1,
    "l2vpn": 1,
    "chassis": 1,
    "ncs-5501": 1,
    "logs": 1,
    "7.5.2": 1,
    "hardware failure": 1,
    "6.6.3": 1
  },
  "merged": true,
  "finalised": true
}


$getField can be used for fields which have periods . or dollars $ in their name. And when that field does not exist, the $type is missing. So use that for $match stage.
Corresponding to that, in the  $project stage, use $setField. Or as I've done below, I'm using $replaceWith instead of $project.
Taking two labels "1.2.3" and "6.5.3" as an example, this would be the aggregation pipeline - each time I've repeated a block for those two labels is where you'd replace it in Python with your list comprehension.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          { "$ne": ["$deleted", true]},
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$ne": [
                  {
                    "$type": {
                      "$getField": { "field": "1.2.3", "input": "$labels" }
                    }
                  },
                  "missing"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$ne": [
                  {
                    "$type": {
                      "$getField": { "field": "6.5.3", "input": "$labels" }
                    }
                  },
                  "missing"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { "$set": { "matching_labels": { "$literal": {} } } },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "command": "$command",
      "matching_labels": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "$setField": {
              "field": "1.2.3",
              "input": "$matching_labels",
              "value": {
                "$getField": { "field": "1.2.3", "input": "$labels" }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$setField": {
              "field": "6.5.3",
              "input": "$matching_labels",
              "value": {
                "$getField": { "field": "6.5.3", "input": "$labels" }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

In this Mongo Playground example, notice that only the fields which exist are set in "matching_labels", because if the value for $setField is missing, then the field does not get set.
Side note: storing "unknown"/dynamic field names with their values, is an anti-pattern. It should be name-value pairs like labels: [{name: "1.2.3", value: 2}, {name: "other", value: 100}, {...}]. Read about the Attribute Pattern.

My previous answer is about using $getField and $setField to solve the specific issue you were facing with . in the field names. This answer is an alternative way to get the same results for the label_list provided.

Use $objectToArray to convert your name-value object to a list of objects in this form [{k: "1.2.3", v: 2}, {k: "other", v: 100}, {...}].

Once again, this is why the Attribute Pattern is better.


Then filter for items where the label in item.k is in your list of labels.
Switch it back to original Object-format using $arrayToObject.
Remove items where there are no matching labels.
Project the necessary fields.

To make this work in Python, add double-quotes, use label_list in place of ["1.2.3", "6.5.3"], and use Python's True instead of JavaScript's true.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { deleted: { $ne: true } }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      matching_labels: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$labels" },
            cond: {
              // your `label_list` here
              $in: ["$$this.k", ["1.2.3", "6.5.3"] ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      matching_labels: { $ne: {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "command": 1,
      "matching_labels": 1
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
